# DAG seems to be missing but code is visible

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG with three tasks which are working perfectly. Each task is a python Operator the DAG is working fine and i am able to view it when function are defined in the same file but as soon as i am moving the function to different file to make the code cleaner and import the same function in to the DAG file it says DAG seems to be missing. The same thing is happening when i am breaking my code using Subdag operator What to do? What may be the error?

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='abcd',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=abcd.efgh,
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so yet, try setting up the main DAG files and their dependencies inside the Airflow 'DAGS' folder as shown in the image below.

[image: 'DAGS' folder in the 'AIRFLOW' home directory]

Then, import the required file from the respective dependency folder into the main DAG file using:

> from dependencies_dag1 import file

Comment: I will try and let you know the results.